# Use css selector or more directly id?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

this more a conceptual question. Recently i found myself to be more confident with this kind of html (example)

```
<div id="mainCont">
  <div id="mainContFirst">Text <span id="mainContFirstSpan">option</span></div>
  <div id="mainContSecond">Other Text</div>
</div>
```

Having all important tag marked with an ID you can easly write down css:

```
#mainContFirst {} etc
```

is this a bad pratice? Should I use just css selector? Is this faster then use selector?

Thanks

## Grouping (edit)

Ok now What about elements that should have the same style?

let's say for example in every divs the second `<span>` should have `font-size:10px;` it's better this:

```
<div>
   text text <span></span> <span id="firstDivSpan"></span>
</div>
 <div>
   text text <span></span> <span id="secondDivSpan"></span>
</div>
```

and then the css:

```
#firstDivSpan, #secondDivSpan {...}
```

Or like this?

```
 <div>
   text text <span></span> <span id="firstDivSpan" class="commonStyle"></span>
</div>
 <div>
   text text <span></span> <span id="secondDivSpan" class="commonStyle"></span>
</div>

.commonStyle{...}
```

What's better?

Comment: Huh? An ID selector is a selector, isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ID selectors are the fastest. That is not bad practice at all; you're simply operating under the assumption that there will only be one element with that ID on your pages.

That said you shouldn't abuse IDs for lame reasons like rendering performance. Use IDs to mark truly unique elements, not to mark everything so you can forget about stuff like descendant combinators, classes, groups etc. Those other selectors are what make CSS so powerful, not just the ID selectors.

**Re question edit:** there isn't any *better* one in this case. Performance issues aside (because *they don't matter at all*) it largely depends on the *meaning* of the selectors.

If your styles apply to any element with the `.commonStyle` class then use the class selector. If you only want to target those two specific `span`s regardless of the class then the ID selectors are more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the ID like in your example.
It is easier for the browser to fetch a particular ID element rather than have to find all parents, then descendants...

As someone expanded on my answer in a separate thread, article regarding this: http://www.css-101.org/descendant-selector/go_fetch_yourself.php

ID, class, element name - they are all CSS selectors.